# heroku django can't load my static files django 2.0.2

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, django-staticfiles

I have been working to fix it for a week but still not find the solution 
I've tried all of the solutions but can't work

my project is fine at local, but when deployed is not like my expect
I have run `collectstatic` on `Heroku` but still not work

the result is like this [my heroku app](http://dikimsyidik.herokuapp.com)

my settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATES_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
#STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '=i(73nmd3&e&m)&@ivj)av4!yrrcle45t#eoegug-4dn4%m^ba'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'portfolio_app',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
     'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'portfolio.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIRS],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'portfolio.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
# add this
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app/staticfiles')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

my wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise


os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "portfolio.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

my index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
 <title>Diki's Portfolio</title>
 <script src="{% static "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" %}" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation.min.css" %}">
 <script src="{% static "bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.min.js" %}" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <script src="{% static "bower_components/normalize-css/normalize.css" %}" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <script src="{% static "bower_components/typed.js/dist/typed.min.js"%}" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <script src="{% static "bower_components/jqcloud2/dist/jqcloud.min.js"%}" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "bower_components/jqcloud2/dist/jqcloud.min.css" %}">
 <script src="{% static "bower_components/custombox/dist/custombox.min.js" %}"></script>
 <link href="{% static "bower_components/custombox/dist/custombox.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Maven+Pro:400,500" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "fonts/foundation-icons/foundation-icons.css" %}">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "styles/styles.css" %}">
</head>

<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="thin-bar">
  </div>

  <section id="about">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 large-8 large-offset-2 columns text-center">
     <img class="img-circle" src="{% static "images/diki.jpg" %}" alt="headshot">
     <div class="details">
      <h2>Hi, I'm Diki. I...<br> <span id="writing-text"><span></h2>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 column">
     <div class="cta text-center">
      <a class="my-button cta-button expand form-button" href="mailto:dikimuhamadsyidik14@hotmail.com">Get In Touch</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 column">
     <div class="my-arrow-div text-center">
      <a href="https://github.com/dikimsyidik"><i class="fa fa-github-alt fa-2x"></i></a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

  </section>


  <section id="experience">

   <div class="row column">
    <div class="small-12">
     <h2 class="text-center">My Experience</h2>
     <p class="text-center tag-line">Specialist in need. Generalist at heart.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns text-center experience-topics">
     <i class="fi-laptop"></i>
     <h3>Front-end</h3>
     <ul>
      <li>html(5)</li>
      <li>css(3)</li>
      <li>Javascript</li>
      <li>Jquery</li>
      <li>Bootstrap</li>
      <li>Semantics-UI</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns text-center experience-topics">
     <i class="fi-database"></i>
     <h3>Back-end</h3>
     <ul>
      <li>SQL</li>
      <li>Restful Web Services</li>
      <li>Flask | Python</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns text-center experience-topics">
     <i class="fi-star"></i>
     <h3>Tools</h3>
     <ul>
      <li>Django</li>
      <li>Bower</li>
      <li>Atom</li>
      <li>Github</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>

  </section>

  <section id="work">
   <h2 class="text-center">Work</h2>
   <div class="row">
    <p class="text-center tag-line">Here are few of my former clients.</p>
   </div>


   <div class="row work-row"> <!-- odd -->
    <div class="small-12 medium-6 medium-push-6 columns">
     <img src="{% static "images/hunter-cole-portfolio-image.png" %}" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-5 medium-pull-7 columns">
     <div class="details details-ftm">
      <h3>Hunter Cole</h3>
      <p class="platform">Web</p>
      <p class="icons"><i class="fi-monitor"></i><i class="fi-tablet-portrait"></i><i class="fi-mobile"></i></p>
      <p>An internationally recognized Scientist and Artist from Loyola University of Chicago.</p>
      <a class="my-button" target="_blank" href="http://huntercole.org">Visit Website</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row work-row"> <!-- even -->
    <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
     <img src="{% static "images/ftm-site.png" %}" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-5 medium-offset-1 columns">
     <div class="details details-ftm">
      <h3>FreshTechMaids</h3>
      <p class="platform">Web</p>
      <p class="icons"><i class="fi-monitor"></i><i class="fi-tablet-portrait"></i><i class="fi-mobile"></i></p>
      <p>FreshTechMaids is a house maid service company.</p>
      <a class="my-button" target="_blank" href="http://www.freshtechmaids.com">Visit Website</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row work-row"> <!-- odd -->
    <div class="small-12 medium-6 medium-push-6 columns">
     <img src="{% static "images/sykora-kitchens.png" %}" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-5 medium-pull-7 columns">
     <div class="details details-ftm">
      <h3>Sykora Kitchens</h3>
      <p class="platform">Web</p>
      <p class="icons"><i class="fi-monitor"></i><i class="fi-tablet-portrait"></i><i class="fi-mobile"></i></p>
      <p>A European kitchens and cabinets manufacturer.</p>
      <a class="my-button" target="_blank" href="http://www.sykorakitchens.com">Visit Website</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>









  </section>

  <section id="teaching">
   <h2 class="text-center">Teaching</h2>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-8 medium-offset-2">
     <p class="text-center tag-line">Here are some of the domains I've helped people with...</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-8 medium-offset-2 columns">
     <div class="teaching-domains">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>

  <section id="footer-cta">
   <h2 class="text-center">Wanna work with me?</h2>
   <p></p>
   <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="small-12 medium-8 medium-offset-2 columns">
     <p class="text-center">I'm currently available for work.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 columns" id="startButtonDiv">
     <a class="my-button form-button" href="mailto:dikimuhamadsyidik14@hotmail.com.com">Start Now</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>

  <footer id="footer">
   <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="small-12 medium-6 medium-offset-3 columns">
     <p id="logo">DMS</p>
     <p id="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2018 | Diki Muhamad Syidik</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </footer>



 </div>
 <script src="{% static "scripts/app.js" %}" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[this is the directory project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afMT1.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be how you structure your static folder. From experiment it seem like in django 2.x.x django expect you to have your static file in a sub folder that corresponds to your app name.

[Reference to other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49322719/django-2-0-3-and-browser-not-showing-static-files/49563551#49563551)