# Django : static files are not loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-staticfiles

i'm trying to test the code mentionned in this page :
[dynamic-formset.js](https://gist.github.com/jteso/2130643)
and i added :

```
<script src="{% static  'js/dynamic-formset.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static  'js/jquery-3.3.1.js' %}"></script>
```

in order to load static files that contains js.
howerver the js doesn't work and i'm getting in the console the following lines :

```
 "GET /static/js/dynamic-formset.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1777
 "GET /static/js/jquery-3.3.1.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1768
```

when i replace the second ligne that imports jquery with the `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js` , i dont get :

```
"GET /static/js/jquery-3.3.1.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1768
```

i only get `"GET /static/js/dynamic-formset.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1777`

do you have any idea why it doesn't work ? i guess that the static files are not loading.
Any help please ? Thank You

Comment: If your files exists in the correct directory, and you're getting a 404 error.  It's typically because your STATIC_URL in settings.py is set incorrectly.  I'd also recommend using a content delivery network for the files instead of a file stored on the server.

Comment: Thank you so much for your replay ; this is my STATIC_URL = '/static/' , and in the beginning of my template i loaded staticfiles :  {% load staticfiles %}

Comment: Thank You So much , it's okey i just noticed that i forgot a directory in my url to dynamic-formset.js

Answer (score 1):

If you are using django 2.x.x make sure your static files are in a sub folder inside the static folder that corresponds to your app name.
[See Other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49322719/django-2-0-3-and-browser-not-showing-static-files/49563551#49563551)